# Why does the object move to the center of the world while Im resizing it?

Tags: objects, object-mode, tilesize

I was in object mode and I added a sphere, I tried to move the sphere and make it smaller, but it didn't work.

I was in object mode the whole time and I did not go into edit mode.

This is what's happening:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you've selected the 3D cursor as pivot point:

[image]

And you've enabled the *Affect Only Locations* option, which moves the object instead of scaling it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works!